# Making a list item take the full width of the parent list

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a display that mimics how a directory of files might be displayed in a file browser or IDE (e.g. Sublime, VSCode, etc..)

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.tree {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #ebedef;
}

.tree-node {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tree-node:hover {
  background-color: #dbdde0;
}

.tree-node span {
  line-height: 18px;
}

.tree-node svg {
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="tree">
    <li style="padding-left: 15px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--directory">
      <span>/</span>
    </li>
    <li style="padding-left: 30px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--directory">
      <span>dir1</span>
    </li>
    <li style="padding-left: 45px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--directory">
      <span>dir2</span>
    </li>
    <li style="padding-left: 60px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--file">
      <span>transformations.js</span>
    </li>
    <li style="padding-left: 45px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--file">
      <span>foo.js</span>
    </li>
    <li style="padding-left: 30px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--file">
      <span>package.json</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

It uses an inline `padding-left` on each element to indent it as needed to form the file structure.

As you hover over a directory or file (e.g. `transformations.js`), it is highlighted with a background color

[image]

The whole display is constrained to `200px` width, but it scrolls to accommodate longer names.

## The problem

[image]

However, when scrolling, the highlight **does not extend* to the full width**. I've tried various combination of nesting `div`s and playing with the `width`, but no luck. **How can I accomplish this?**

I'm having trouble with the fact that

1. Each item / line has a different width
2. Each item / line has a custom `padding-left` set as an offset

I'm open to refactoring the structure in any way needed to make this work visually.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you're not using nested lists rather than padding? That's the usual approach. The list doesn't make much semantic sense otherwise and you might just as well use divs and avoid this whole problem.

Comment: Thanks, I had not considered nesting them. If I used `div` instead, how would it help here? Can they be positioned differently?

Comment: Lists have peculiar layout nuances that can be troublesome. Adding padding to divs doesn't cause this same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply width calculations for each level. This gets your styles out of your markup, too.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.tree {
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #ebedef;
}

.tree-node {
  width: calc(100% + 15px);
  height: 18px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: pink;
}

.tree-node.level-1 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  width: calc(100% + 75px);
}

.tree-node.level-2 {
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: calc(100% + 60px);
}

.tree-node.level-3 {
  padding-left: 45px;
  width: calc(100% + 45px);
}

.tree-node.level-4 {
  padding-left: 60px;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
}

.tree-node:hover {
  background-color: #dbdde0;
}

.tree-node span {
  line-height: 18px;
}

.tree-node svg {
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="tree">
    <li tabindex="0" class="tree-node level-1 tree-node--directory">
      <span>/</span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="tree-node level-2 tree-node--directory">
      <span>dir1</span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="tree-node level-3 tree-node--directory">
      <span>dir2</span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="tree-node level-4 tree-node--file">
      <span>transformations.js</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Neat! This seems to work for the example. One question - when defining `calc(100% + X)` for each level - how did you determine `X` was `75px`, `60px`, `45px`, and `30px`? And how would this accommodate the case of an even longer file name?

Comment: There's a mathematical pattern there based on your initial padding. I work a lot in Chrome's document inspector to verify what works. It shouldn't matter what the overall size is.

Comment: Thanks! I've marked it as accepted, but I'm curious if you could elaborate on the pattern. It seems like the padding + extra width always add up to `90px`, and with each indent the padding increases whereas the extra width decreases, linearly. But why `90px` specifically? And what happens at some high value like `level-20`? Will the width just be `calc(100% + 0px)`?

Comment: I really couldn't say. It's a trial-and-error thing. Something to do with how width is calculated by the rendering engine for list elements. As I mentioned in a comment above, layout can be tricky with lists.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `display:grid` to tree element. You may need to also adjust the alignment:

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.tree {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #ebedef;
  /* added */
  display:grid;
  align-content:flex-start;
  /**/
}

.tree-node {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tree-node:hover {
  background-color: #dbdde0;
}

.tree-node span {
  line-height: 18px;
}

.tree-node svg {
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="tree">
    <li style="padding-left: 15px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--directory">
      <span>/</span>
    </li>
    <li style="padding-left: 30px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--directory">
      <span>dir1</span>
    </li>
    <li style="padding-left: 45px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--directory">
      <span>dir2</span>
    </li>
    <li style="padding-left: 60px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--file">
      <span>transformations.js</span>
    </li>
    <li style="padding-left: 45px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--file">
      <span>foo.js</span>
    </li>
    <li style="padding-left: 30px;" tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--file">
      <span>package.json</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide `width: 100%;` to the li element and you are good to go. It will work exactly as you want it to. You can either use nth-child selector or you can just do it for all of the li elements so that each element has the same behaviour.

If you want to do it using javascript then it would be a little easier. What you need to do is

```
// Get the scroll width of your ul
const scrollWidth = document.querySelector("ul.tree").scrollWidth;
// Now select the li element or all of them and put them in a loop 
// for now I'm doing it for the first one just for simplicity
// but the same goes for all of the others
const element = document.querySelector("li");

element.style.width = scrollWidth + "px";
// You can console log scroll width to see what it outputs
```

Another way using css
You have to do it separately for different elements. For example, the elements with 30px padding can have one rule but the ones with 60px padding on left will have slight change in it

```
/* select the particular li element */
/* in this case assume I have given p-30 class to all elements with 30px of padding */

.p-30 {
   width: calc(100% + 30px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it looks like this solution relies on JavaScript. Is there a way to implement this purely in CSS? Or is the only option to find `scrollWidth` using JS?

Comment: There might be a way to do it with css ( I don't have any ) but I think that would be a clutter for this small functionality which can be achieved with 2 lines of js

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `display: block` instead of `display: flex` and to add the padding to the spans. The problem is that the `.tree` doesn't cover the whole `container` but without the scroll. I couldn't find a solution without Javascript.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const tree = document.querySelector('.tree');
tree.style.width = container.scrollWidth + 'px';
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
.container{
    min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px; 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background-color: #ebedef;
}
.tree {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: block;
}

.tree-node {
  display: block;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tree-node:hover {
  background-color: #dbdde0;
}

span {
  line-height: 18px;
  display:block;
}
svg {
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="tree">
    <li tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--directory">
      <span style="padding-left: 15px;">/</span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--directory">
      <span >dir1</span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--directory">
      <span style="padding-left: 45px;">dir2</span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--file">
      <span style="padding-left: 60px;">transformations.js</span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--file">
      <span style="padding-left: 45px;">foo.js</span>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0" class="tree-node tree-node--file">
      <span style="padding-left: 30px;">package.json</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Javascript is not tagged but in this case gives a solution. Actually it's a very good case when HTML and CSS are not enough to solve a task. It was very beneficial to me to play with the code.